# PHP Show System

Tags: php

This code is supposted Show all of the Table Reg_Log.
The code can show but... if the table is empty, the code show a message saying "You have no purchases.".

but someting is wrong...

```
        $Check_Reg = $_SESSION['user']['username'];

    if(!empty($Check_Reg))
        {

        $dbh = new PDO("mysql:host={$host};dbname={$dbname};charset=utf8", $username, $password);           
        $search = $dbh->prepare("SELECT ID_Article, Data_Compra, Price, Cred_Depois FROM reg_log ORDER BY Data_Compra DESC");           
        $search->execute();         
        $checkUser = $search->fetchAll();

             foreach($checkUser as $u)
              {
              echo "<table>";
              echo "<tr>";
              echo "<th><b>Article ID</b></th>";
              echo "<th><b>Price</b></th>";
              echo "<th><b>Savings</b></th>";
              echo "<th><b>Data & Hora</b></th>";

              echo "</tr>";
              echo "<br /><tr><td>" . $u['ID_Article'] . "</td><td>". $u['Price'] . "</td><td>" . $u['Cred_Depois'] . "</td><td>" . $u['Data_Compra'] . "</td></tr> " ;
              echo "</table>";


        $dbh = null; //close db
        }    

        } else {     
                $emptyField = False;    
            echo "You have no purchases.";

    }
```

Comment: do `var_dump($Check_Reg);` and see if it's empty or not.

Comment: You state `but someting is wrong`. Care to explain what is wrong?

Comment: Some possible issues, just a guess until you clarify - (1) your query selects all rows, and not the ones specific to `$_SESSION['user']['username']`. (2) You are building a table for each row, instead of 1 table with all the rows below. (3) you have `$dbh = null;` inside your loop, where it should be outside the loop. These are just a few of all the possible issues.

Comment: Or is your question, what to do when your query to `reg_log` returns `0` rows? Currently your `You have no purchases.` is echo'ed on the `else{}` of `if(!empty($Check_Reg))`. Do you want it to be when `count($checkUser) == 0`?

Answer (score 0):

Because `$_SESSION['user']['username']` is empty, the table isn't even read.

Comment: So, How can i complete my script? I Just need a script that show a unique user... but that is showing all Table... Can u help me?

Comment: And how is the user related to that table? Where do you get the user information (id? username?) from?